# Passing function name as string + Panda Dataframe + Azure Databricks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I got a function called 'changeUpper', i want call this function on a given column of Pandas DataFrame based on Metadata definitions.

***Example*** in Metadata I record to call function `changeUpper` on `PrimaryColumn` (this holds name of the Column).

I wanted to do something like which will be dynamic:

```
for index, row in rulesPandas.iterrows():  
    sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']] = sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(ow['FunctionName'])
```

throw error: `*changeUpper is an unknown string function*`

Alternatively what am doing right now is as below which is not so flexible, whenever i add new function have to add another `if` condition.

```
for index, row in rulesPandas.iterrows():  
  if row['FunctionName'] == 'changeUpper':
    sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']] = sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(changeUpper)
```

Comment: func = eval(row['FunctionName'])  and then .apply(func) works.

Comment: can't you keep function name instead of string ? `row['FunctionName'] = changeUpper` instead of `row['FunctionName'] =  "changeUpper"` ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working as :

```
for index, row in rulesPandas.iterrows():
    func = eval(row['FunctionName'])
    newcolumn = row['NewColumnName']
    if(newcolumn is not None):
      sourcePandas = sourcePandas.assign(**{f'{newcolumn}': sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(func)})
    else: 
      sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']] = sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(func)
```

What am trying to achieve is to execute assigned function against given column, this is defined in metadata.